# Error con vue-router

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

Estimados no puedo renderizar la vista por que me dice este error:

```
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #/about
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #/home
```

Asi es como me queda la url:

```
http://localhost/cloud/cloud/public/#/home
```

Estoy usando Laravel + Vuejs + Vue-Router

Links:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="ftco-nav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">

        <router-link  to='/home' exact  data-target="#home" class="nav-link" >Inicio</router-link>

        </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <router-link   to='/about' class="nav-link">Sobre nosotros</router-link>
        </li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="domain.html" class="nav-link">Precios</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="blog.html" class="nav-link">Blog</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="contact.html" class="nav-link">Contacto</a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
```

app.js

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter)

let routes = [

  {path:'/home',component:require('./components/cloud/homeComponent.vue').default},
  {path:'/about',component:require('./components/cloud/aboutComponent.vue').default}

]

const router =  new VueRouter({
  routes

})

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,

  })
```

web.php

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('app');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

En tu archivo web.php agrega esto

```
Route::get('/{vue_capture?}', function () {return view('app');})>where('vue_capture', '[\/\w\.-]*');
```

En tu archivo app.js agrega en tu router  `mode: 'history'`

```
const router =  new VueRouter({
   mode: 'history',
   routes
})
```

En tu app.view o donde tengas el diseño principal, agrega `<router-view></router-view>` dentro del div con id **app**

```
<div id="app">
   <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

Comment: SI, ya lo habia probado, el problema es que cuando hago clic en "inicio" o "sobre nosotros", la url no se mantiene y en vez de ir a `http://localhost/cloud/cloud/public/#/home` va a ´http://localhost/home´

Comment: Tampoco me levanta el componente, me modifica la url pero no puedo ver el contenido del componente.